# react-breadcrumbs throwing error when using with router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, breadcrumbs

React Breadcrumbs is throwing some error when using with Router.

I am following this tutorial for implementation.

http://learnreact.robbestad.com/breadcrumbs

**Below is the code:**

```
var Breadcrumbs = require('react-breadcrumbs');

const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <MegaMenu />
          {Breadcrumbs}
          <Route exact path='/' name='HomePage' component={HomePage}/>
          <Route path='/celebrity' name='Celebrities' component={Celebrities}/>
          <Route path='/axios' name='Axios' component={Axios}/>
          <Route path='/brands' name='Brands' component={Brands}/>
          <Footer />
        </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

**Below is the error:**

***Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Breadcrumb, Breadcrumbs}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.***

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass the reference directly but use it with `React.createElement` or in other words, in `JSX` land you should do just `<Breadcrumbs />`.

If you look carefully at the code from the link you posted (http://learnreact.robbestad.com/breadcrumbs):

```
var Breadcrumbs = require('react-breadcrumbs');

MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
     return (
       <div>
            <Breadcrumbs />{/* You see it here, <Breadcrumbs /> not {Breadcrumbs} */}
       </div>
    );
  }
});
```

It creates new React element and now let's check your code:

```
var Breadcrumbs = require('react-breadcrumbs');

const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <MegaMenu />
          {Breadcrumbs}{/* <-------- Here is the issue */}
          <Route exact path='/' name='HomePage' component={HomePage}/>
          <Route path='/celebrity' name='Celebrities' component={Celebrities}/>
          <Route path='/axios' name='Axios' component={Axios}/>
          <Route path='/brands' name='Brands' component={Brands}/>
          <Footer />
        </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

If you replace `{Bredcrumbs}` with `<Breadcrumbs />`, it should just work:

```
var Breadcrumbs = require('react-breadcrumbs');

const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <MegaMenu />
          <Breadcrumbs />
          <Route exact path='/' name='HomePage' component={HomePage}/>
          <Route path='/celebrity' name='Celebrities' component={Celebrities}/>
          <Route path='/axios' name='Axios' component={Axios}/>
          <Route path='/brands' name='Brands' component={Brands}/>
          <Footer />
        </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

You can read more about JSX in the official React documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score -1):

I have used this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-breadcrumbs-dynamic][1] to implement the breadcrumbs.

**Created one route.js and imported the library**

```
import { Breadcrumb as BootstrapBreadcrumb } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Breadcrumbs, BreadcrumbsItem } from 'react-breadcrumbs-dynamic';
import CrumbItem from '../components/common/breadcrumb/CrumbItem';
```

**Created the breadcrumbs container like this in route.js:**

```
const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <div className="breadcrumbs-container">
        <BreadcrumbsItem glyph='home' to={base_path}>
          Home Page
        </BreadcrumbsItem>
        <Breadcrumbs
          hideIfEmpty={{ active: true }}
          item={CrumbItem}
          container={BootstrapBreadcrumb}
          finalProps={{ active: true }}
          duplicateProps={{ to: 'href' }}
        />
      </div>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
      <Route path='/brands' component={Brands} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**Given breadcrumbs items in Another component brands.js**

```
import { BreadcrumbsItem } from 'react-breadcrumbs-dynamic';
        render() {
        return (
        <BreadcrumbsItem to={'/brands'}>
          Brands
        </BreadcrumbsItem>
        )
    }
```

**Created link container separately**

```
import { Breadcrumb } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'

const CrumbItem = ({to, ...props}) => (
  <LinkContainer to={to}>
    <Breadcrumb.Item {...props}>
    </Breadcrumb.Item>
  </LinkContainer>
)

export default CrumbItem
```

**Note: Using bootstrap is optional**

Comment: @Zoe : Edited the post and demonstrated how I have implemented and solved my problem, I hope this is fine now.